# Don't migrate old off-topic questions in the Close Votes review queue

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review, vote-to-close

I've just come across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/561367), from the Close Votes section of the new review page. It's over two years old and has two answers, one accepted.

It also has 4 Off-Topic close votes for it to be migrated to Super User. Personally, I'd like to vote to close this as Not Constructive. However, if I do so I'll immediately ship this off to Super User, where I suspect Sathya will hunt me down with the intention of causing me pain :-).

Shouldn't one of the following happen instead?

1. Automatically close old questions with 4 migration votes without migrating them (not such a good idea; it means that 5 people haven't reviewed the question, which is not so good)
2. Exclude old questions that might get migrated from the review queues (better but it means close worthy questions might never get closed).
3. On old questions count a close vote but don't migrate.

The definition of "old" is up in the air :-).

---

I don't know if the Review links are permanent so here is [a permanent link to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559914/handy-tool-to-draw-transparent-icon-for-iphone-app).

Comment: The issue here is that you voting to close as non-constructive triggers a migration. (Same issue the other way round)

Comment: That question was both too old to migrate and not high enough quality to foist upon another site.  Moderator close votes ignore the reason selected by other close voters, so I went ahead and closed it as off-topic.  Flagging for moderator attention in these cases is one alternative, but we might not always act quickly enough to catch a question before it's moved.

Comment: Now that's an idea...how about just disabling migration after X months or something for non-mods?

Comment: Precisely... it'd solve problems caused by the new review queues (I think). It _seems_ like it's happening a lot more often now.

Comment: Hmm ... [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2800527/590790) just got closed through the review queue as off-topic after I voted to close as it belongs on [TeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/). However, it did not get migrated automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I defined "old" as "[60 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151890/disable-migration-for-questions-older-than-60-days)". Three things now prevent migrations of questions older than this:

1. It's [not possible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151890/disable-migration-for-questions-older-than-60-days) to vote for migration on questions older than 60 days.
2. Close votes specifying a migration target on questions older than 60 days are discarded.
3. There's [an extra check](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198578/question-was-migrated-64-days-after-being-posted/198611#198611) when a question is closed that prevents migration if it is older than 60 days.

Combined, these should greatly reduce the chances of old questions being closed just because someone thinks there's a better site for it, and from being migrated if they are closed.

If an old question is legitimately off-topic and is closed as such, but would be appropriate for another site, raise the issue here on meta - to date, these cases have been fairly rare.