# Flagging question as off topic - where is ServerFault option?

Tags: support, flags

I notice a lot of questions tagged VMware should be migrated to ServerFault, but the option is not available as you can see in the picture below.  Is there a way to pick what options show up here?

[image: belongs on options]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Too many bad questions were being migrated from Stack Overflow to Server Fault.  Rather than letting that continue to happen, Server Fault was removed from the list. See: [Regarding the high number of rejected migrations from Stack Overflow to Server Fault](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/150206/1288).

The migration list is not customizable, so if you see a post that you think should be migrated to a site not on the list you have to flag it for moderator attention.  Please only do this if you're *very* familiar with the target site.  Moderators often aren't, and we don't want to be responsible for more bad migration.