# Why does Super User site appear twice in vote-to-close dialog?

Tags: support, close-reasons, off-topic

Super User appears in both the main Off-Topic list and the Migration list of the close dialog. Is this a bug or intentional?

I also don't really understand why Server Fault appears in the main Off-Topic list and not the Migration list, apart from it being new.

Here:

[image]

and:

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The top one is a general off-topic reason explaining what is off-topic on the site (and includes a link to Super User as way of explaining to the OP that the question may be more suitable there). The link to Super User complements the explanation (no general computing software and hardware questions).

The lower one is an actual migration vote - note that you get there by selecting the "This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network" off-topic reason.

Comment: So if 5 people vote it as a general hard/software question that probably belongs on [su], it won't get migrated? Aren't people already bad enough at voting (according to a comment by another mod which would be a lot of effort to find now) that giving them **more** (very similar) options is ill-advised?

Comment: @Dukeling - It is subtle, but yes, if people vote to close as something that doesn't belong on [SO] rather than something that belongs elsewhere, then it will not be migrated.

Comment: @Dukeling Super User is just an example, `Off Topic for SO != On Topic for SU` ...there are plenty of questions that are neither.

Comment: And another thing, do we expect the general voting-to-close public to be able to figure out this difference all on their own, find their way here in search of this or even notice that it's at both places for that matter?

Comment: @Dukeling - Don't forget that these close reasons are still _new_ and we are still in the process of fine-tuning them. By all means, post a [meta-tag:feature-request] to change it.

Comment: For the record, as a moderator on Super User, I **strongly dislike** close reasons that point to another site without migrating the question. It simply encourages new users to go and re-ask the _exact same question_ on SU (or SF or wherever) without making any changes, when 99% of the time the reason the question wasn't straight-up migrated is because it was low-quality for reasons beyond merely being off-topic. **If a question is _bad_, we shouldn't be encouraging users to re-ask it verbatim elsewhere**, we should be telling them _what else is wrong with it too_ so they can fix it.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is just a potential explanation of where the OP might go instead, and is not the only choice, just one of many. Whereas the second one is a direct "this absolutely belongs on Super User."

As for why Server Fault is mentioned in the former but not the latter, from time to time the list of migration targets change to reflect the actual use patterns of the site. Why Server Fault is no longer in the list is explained by:

[Regarding the high number of rejected migrations from Stack Overflow to Server Fault](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/150206/regarding-the-high-number-of-rejected-migrations-from-stack-overflow-to-server-f)