# Where's the "belongs on serverfault.com" question close reason?

Tags: support, migration

I've seen a couple of questions recently that IMHO would be better suited to [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/).  Here's one [specific example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20831025/hostnames-in-haproxy-configuration-file).

I couldn't see such site listed in the close dialog though:

[image]

What am I missing and what's the *proper protocol* to migrate such questions to their respective SE site?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There have been [too many failed migrations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/150206/regarding-the-high-number-of-rejected-migrations-from-stack-overflow-to-server-f/152596#152596); the site has been removed from that list.

Flag for moderator attention instead (use 'other' and explain to a moderator that you feel the question would be suitable), or just use the custom 'off-topic' reason Stack Overflow has for just such questions (the one that *suggests* that Server Fault might be a site to ask):

> Questions on **professional server, networking, or related infrastructure administration** are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/about).

Using this option won't actually migrate the question; rather it is meant to let the user know the site *exists*.

Answer (score 0):

The migration paths shown are the most common paths (which are not commonly misused). It is considered dangerous to have other paths as community members cannot reasonably be expected to know what is on topic on every other site in the network.

Migrations to other sites can be requested by flagging for moderator attention