# Closing question as off-topic has no options to move to another site (main SO)

Tags: discussion, bug, status-bydesign, vote-to-close, off-topic

I spend some time every day reviewing questions (including "close question" queue).  If I select "close as off-topic", I usually get a sub-selection of options to move the question to another site: meta.SO, dba.SE, serverfault, superuser, etc.  This is the correct behaviour, or at least the one I've come to expect.

However sometimes, randomly (I haven't figured out the pattern), the sub-selection is not available, I can still select "off-topic", but can't select to move the question to another site.  The screenshot below demonstrates this.  Selecting another option (e.g. "not constructive") and then "off-topic" again does not help.

Is this a bug or a feature?

**EDIT:** This screenshot is Firefox on Linux, but I have also encountered this with Firefox on Mac.

[image]

Comment: I can confirm, that this happens :)

Comment: Never seen this. What browser & OS?

Comment: I've seen it happen more often when there are already a number of votes cast. Maybe if a mathematical consensus can not be reached with the remaining number of votes it doesn't present you with all the options.

Comment: @Mat I updated the question: have seen in in firefox on linux and firefox on mac.

Comment: Questions older than 60 days cannot be migrated any more. [Disable migration for questions older than 60 days](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151890/disable-migration-for-questions-older-than-60-days)

Comment: @ChrisF A-ha! That answers the question.  It's not like I specifically look for questions to close - I usually just work along the queue until I exhaust my daily votes.  Thanks for clarifying the issue then.  I guess it's not a bug then.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[That question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454247/list-of-projects-open-source-close-source) was posted back in 2010, over two years ago. I don't think it was a particularly constructive question back then (and it certainly didn't get a comprehensive set of answers) - moving it to another site *now* will almost certainly accomplish nothing useful.

That's why [migration is disabled for questions older than 60 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151890/disable-migration-for-questions-older-than-60-days). Just close it where it sits, rather than dumping it on another site.

Comment: Great, thanks.  I agree with "do not move old questions" policy, just didn't put the 2 and 2 together correctly.