# Why can't I migrate this particular question?

Tags: support, migration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Closing question as off-topic has no options to move to another site (main SO)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152655/closing-question-as-off-topic-has-no-options-to-move-to-another-site-main-so)

I'm a mod and I'm attempting to migrate [this question](http://answers.onstartups.com/questions/27992/multiple-keywords-content-generation-seo-strategy) to Webmasters, but for some reason I can't.

After clicking close > offtopic, I'm supposed to get the option to migrate to another site, but I'm not seeing that for this question. Instead of this:

[image]

I get this:

[image]

I tested it on a couple of other questions on the site and they worked fine. Why am I not seeing the option to migrate for this particular question? Is this a bug? Could it be that the question has passed some age threshold for migration? If it's an age issue with the question, what can be done about this? I [asked Webmasters](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6957183#6957183) before attempting to migrate it, and they said they wanted the question.

Comment: You can thank Shog9 for this one: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151890/disable-migration-for-questions-older-than-60-days

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ That explains a lot :-)

Comment: Given that the asker has accepted an answer and moved on, you should probably just close it as off-topic if you don't want it. Note that Webmasters has several similar questions already (example: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/21570/how-do-i-do-seo-for-multiple-search-keywords-that-are-similar-but-not-the-same), but adding a comment linking to the site for future readers would not go amiss.

Comment: @Shog9 I asked Webmasters and they said they wanted it. I can see the benefit of blocking regular users from migrating these questions, but what's the point of blocking mods from doing it? If mods on both sites agree with the migration, what's the problem?

Comment: #1, it really shouldn't be the mods hashing this out - a re-occurring problem with migrations has been a lack of understanding of the scope of related sites by the *general membership* on the sites; pushing the decisions off on the mods doesn't do anything for this. #2, what good does it do to migrate an old, answered question to a site where the existing answers may not be seen as useful and the author(s) aren't around to address criticisms? Migrate *new* questions when there's a good chance they'll do better in their new location and the asker is around to respond to feedback.

Comment: @Shog9 #1, If you had actually looked at the link I provided, you would have seen that this wasn't some super secret mod action. I asked about the migration in the Webmasters chatroom, so that anyone in the Webmasters community could jump in. #2, It's not for me (or you) to decide what is appropriate for the Webmasters site. That should be left up to the Webmasters community. If the folks there are happy with a question and would like to see it migrated to their site, what is the big deal?

Comment: @Zuly: what's wrong with it where it sits? In over a year, it had all of one close vote, no discussion indicating it was off-topic, and seemed to be doing fine - past discussions on SEO seem to indicate it was accepted. If this has changed, shouldn't there be some indication of this? Regardless, old migrations have been too troublesome and so they're now prohibited across the board; there is currently one exceptional case defined for mass-migrations: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152597/how-to-migrate-old-questions-to-a-new-graduated-site

Comment: @Shog9 You are getting way off-topic here. This isn't a discussion about what questions or topics are on-topic on OnStartups. If you have an opinion on the matter, feel free to post something on our meta or chime in on this [previous thread](http://meta.answers.onstartups.com/questions/926/are-questions-related-to-websites-on-topic). I'm merely asking about the general topic of migrating old questions here.

Comment: *In general*, it causes problems. So it's no longer allowed. For anyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is too old.  Questions that have been asked more than 60 days ago cannot be migrated, even by a moderator.

Comment: This answer is just as correct as mine, not sure why it was downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

The question is too old. You cannot migrate questions that are older than 60 days, and that question was asked 15 months or so ago.