# Explain why a 60 day old post can't be migrated when voting off-topic

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, migration, vote-to-close

There have been a number of Meta posts confused as to [Why can't I migrate this particular question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156254/why-cant-i-migrate-this-particular-question) There's no feedback indicating why you don't get the "belongs on" menu when selecting the option, so I'm not surprised:

[image]

A section should pop-out below the Off Topic block explaining why you can only vote off topic, not to migrate, when the 60 day limit has been reached for a post. This should alleviate a lot of the confusion, and you could toss in a link to the official meta post about the feature change to explain the reasoning too.

Comment: I think this should be extended to flags as well. And somehow detect custom flags that say "belongs on ..." I get those every now and then only to find out I can't migrate stuff because it's older than 60 days.

Comment: Exactly, someone explain it to me, because right now, I can't see the reasoning to prevent this in *all* cases.

Comment: @NullUserException What, even magical moderator powers can't do that? I'm shocked, I tell you, just shocked! I need a waffle to recover…

Comment: The title of this **feature-request** is misleading. When I read "Explain why a 60 day old post can't be migrated when voting off-topic," I thought this post was an actual question requesting information about why [a 60-day-old post can't be migrated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151890/disable-migration-for-questions-older-than-60-days). *Please reword the title.*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Starting with the next build the "off topic" close reason will have "(too old to migrate)" after it if that is in fact the case.

Answer (score 19):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This would be a good addition. There are many complexities to the migration system that are not at all intuitive or obvious to most users.

Doing this should improve the signal to noise ratio on Meta, and possibly on other sites as well.