# Explicitly state that a question is too old to migrate instead of omitting the option entirely

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flags, migration, close-reasons

Questions older than 60 days can't be migrated by moderators. The way this is currently implemented in the flagging and closing UI is that the option "This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network" is simply missing from the dialog.

I think it would be better to disable the option and replace it with a text explaining that the question is too old to migrate. Users that are not active on meta often don't know about this restriction and might get confused. And even experienced users sometimes forget about this restriction if they don't pay attention to the age of the question.

Comment: I am a recent offender at SO and I think what caught me out was a poor new answer to an old question I reviewed on my iPhone. It would have been an easy question for the site I suggested.

Comment: And/Or add this as a standard decline reason on the moderator flag processing dialog. We'd use it every day on SO.

Comment: I seem to recall the dialog saying this in the past.  Am I right?  And if so, why was it removed?

Comment: @psubsee2003 I don't think this was ever the case, but I might be wrong.

Comment: @MadScientist found what I was remembering.  Back when off-topic only meant off-topic, it used to do [show something in the vote-to-close dialog](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156257/explain-why-a-60-day-old-post-cant-be-migrated-when-voting-off-topic).  Robert's answer was similar to what was implemented.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yeah, this [already exists](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156257/explain-why-a-60-day-old-post-cant-be-migrated-when-voting-off-topic), but we introduced a bug at some point.

Instead of looking at whether the site has any migration paths defined at all, we were checking whether any were valid for the question itself... which, of course, for a question that's too old to migrate is an empty list.

A fix will be live with the next build (rev 2015.2.6.3061 here on meta, and  2015.2.6.2281 elsewhere).

Comment: Those pesky bugs, [they all need to be squashed.](http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQki6QWl4X3YUe_nqwcFk3qwJLQoqqwZCovcI8MTANdWF3I2jd-Tg)