# “too old to migrate” doesn’t show on meta sites

Tags: bug, migration, close-reasons, per-site-meta

When the 60 day limit has been reached for a question on a main site, the option for the “off topic” close reason is changed from

> **off-topic because...**

to

> **off-topic because… (too old to migrate)**

See also [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/156894/271002).

On a meta site, however, the option stays

> **off-topic because...**

without the additional explanation. But still, in the next step, the option “This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network” disappears.

(Tested as a moderator on [chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com) and [german.meta.stackexchange.com](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com))

See also [this related question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/247112/271002).

Comment: It was probably overlooked for per-site metas since there are no migration paths normal users can migrate to.