# In flagging dialog, IF "too old to migrate" THEN remove the tip "... or belongs on another Stack Exchange site"

Tags: bug, design, flags, migration, old-questions

I spotted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53800051/repository-does-not-have-a-release-file-error) which I think clearly belongs on [another site](https://askubuntu.com/). I tried to flag that, and one of the options was "needs improvement", which includes the situation where

> "This question (...) belongs on another Stack Exchange site."

(by the way, this is questionable - does migration really *improve* a question? It moves it, not changes it)

[image]

However, the next screen **doesn't have the option to flag for migration**. And the only reason I figured out it was too old to migrate is because the second radio button has (too old to migrate) included in brackets. (And by the way, I find this is questionable writing style: why is it in brackets in the "header" and not in the "body" of the radio button? *Too old to migrate* is the context, but not the *reason to flag*). In fact, I didn't understand the description of this second radio button, but I googled "too old to migrate" and only then figured out that this question was exactly that, too old to migrate.

["Explain why a 60 day old post can't be migrated when voting off-topic"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156257/explain-why-a-60-day-old-post-cant-be-migrated-when-voting-off-topic) and others are clearly related, but I think it is not equivalent to my question because **the current UI has *two* issues**:

1. Not only it doesn't explain *why* a question can't be migrated

What's worse,

2. It starts by hinting that it *can* when it actually *cannot be migrated*

I suggest that IF the question is too old to migrate, THEN the first dialog should include a statement like "if you think this question should be migrated then note that it's too old, but here are your other options", perhaps with a link to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247112/explicitly-state-that-a-question-is-too-old-to-migrate-instead-of-omitting-the-o).

I do hope it's ok I capitalized the `IF` and `THEN` in my Question Title, my intention was to indicate that it seems like an easy thing to code into the engine.

[image]

Comment: IMO, it would be better to change that portion of the text to something like "or does not belong on this Stack Exchange site." That would be both substantially more accurate as to what closure means and remain valid regardless of the ability to migrate the question.

Comment: Being in the wrong place is the entire point of migration; being in the correct place instead is definitely an improvement.