# Why is this question off topic for SO?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, closed-questions

I like looking at old questions where I got a new upvote, and today happened across this one:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902003/functional-and-non-functional-requirments/902032#902032

closed as being off topic.

Now look, folks, I've been a programmer and software engineer for more than 40 years. I can't *think* of a topic that's a lot more on-topic -- or important -- for a professional programmer than understanding the difference between functional and nonfunctional requirements.

Comment: The question states _but what could be possible requirements? Any ideas ?_ The problem with that is it very open-ended and could lead to discussion. I would say that it should have been closed as not constructive instead of off-topic though.

Comment: I would have voted for closing as *not a real question* because of being to broad.

Comment: Or 'too localized' as it explains the functional and non functional requirements for a specific game.

Comment: Did not see the question as it is already deleted, but maybe [Programmers Stackexchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) is a better place to ask this. There is also already a [question about functional and non-functional requirements](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/118376/functional-or-non-functional-requirement#118407).

Comment: @w4rumy It's over 60 days old, it can't be migrated. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156254/why-cant-i-migrate-this-particular-question

Comment: Okay, I've now been a programmer for almost 50 years, this question is still being downvoted, and you all are still wrong. But what the hell, I get a lot of consulting work because I can come in and fix things when someone didn't understand the nonfunctional requirements.

Comment: Why was this question downvoted so heavily?

Comment: People were embarrassed.

Answer (score 16):

This is not just about whether your question is on topic for software engineers. It is also - and more importantly - about whether it is on-topic for Stack Overflow. The site's [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions) states that the following topics are considered on-topic for Stack Overflow:

> - a specific programming problem
> - a software algorithm
> - software tools commonly used by programmers
> - practical, answerable problems that are unique to software development

None of these apply to the question in question. So your question may be on-topic for software engineering, but is clearly off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 10):

This question has several... issues with it.

- Off topic: As another answerer has stated, it's [not in our scope](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173421/16587). But let's say I'm wrong about that. Why else could it be closed?
- Not a Real Question: It's an impossibly broad question:  You could come up with various requirements until you're blue.
- Too Localized: How many people will benefit from this specific question? There's no way to generalize it; it's about a specific paper that a specific university is using for their class assignment.  Outside of that group of people, no one else will find this question.
- Not constructive: Too many possible answers, too much ability for discussion. Which one is the 'right' answer?  How do we know objectively that it's right?

It also requires a link to a PDF to download even to answer. What happens when that link dies? The entire question becomes useless.

If:

- The question would be in the text and not in the PDF, and
- If, somehow, the OP could make the question a larger question about functional and non functional requirements and
- If, somehow, the OP could make a discernibly objective answer criteria

It'd probably still be off topic, but it'd be a lot closer to scope than it is currently.

As it stands,the question is so far outside of scope that even talking about it is just attracting rubber-neckers. I've deleted it. 10K users can edit it and flag it for un-deletion.  We've got a lot of borderline questions we can talk about, but I just don't see this as one of them.

Answer (score 4):

[FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) mentions:

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual
>   problems that you face. **Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the
>   usefulness of our site** and push other questions off the front page.
>
> Your questions should be reasonably scoped. **If you can imagine an
>   entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.**

Though it was a software engineering question but **not inline with FAQ**, so it was correctly closed.