# Why was this question of mine which can be answered objectively closed?

Tags: discussion, support, software-engineering-se

**New Question:**

After some really good info on the topic from fellow meta folks, I would love to ask the mods to migrate the question in question to Programmers. Is it not possible?

---

**Old Question:**

I want to learn a new language (for myself) and I am seeing to some options. I have a question about Ruby after I'm baffled by the Ruby philosophy **there's more than one way to do it**. This is one thing that is often repeated in almost all threads, forums that discuss about Ruby or that pits it against other major languages. Coming from a C#, Java background can't I know what does that statement mean? Isn't there an objective answer for something that is often talked about as the fundamental philosophy of a language? I got an answer for the question, and I know vaguely now what that means, but does this question really deserve to be closed?

["In Ruby there's more than one way of doing the same thing" - what does this mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6401361/in-ruby-theres-more-than-one-way-of-doing-the-same-thing-what-does-this-mea)

I request you kindly to vote to reopen the question.

**Edit:** Can I know why the question can't be answered objectively or why the question doesn't belong to acceptable questions in SO? I would love to see an answer in that direction. It can help people who would have to contribute to the answer and future visitors who would want to learn about the same.

Someone pointed about migrating it to Programmers and I second that. If it can be done please take the measures. If it has to be CW, then shall we do that? If not please give me some direction on `Why is it not fit for SO` rather than complaints like its old, I already got answer etc.

Comment: You're asking about a question that's over a year old?  What purpose would be served by reopening it?

Comment: I agree this is an edge case, but you got a good answer already. Why reopen it now?

Comment: @RobertHarvey may be someone could answer his question now. More than that why keep a question closed (for no reason I find)? I have many questions open which are more than a yr old.

Comment: `"I have many questions open which are more than a yr old"` -- I suspect they are all on-topic.

Comment: @Pekka I have many questions open which are more than a yr old. The point is not about `reopening now`. its about `not closing a legit question`

Comment: It's not a legit question in its current form. With some editing, it might become one.

Comment: It's probably more suited for Programmers.SE, but it's too old to be migrated there.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes, so that's the underlying point here. Is my question on topic or not. Shall we not discuss on that point rather than "whats the point of reopening an old question?"

Comment: @Pekka can you give suggestions?

Comment: It's not on-topic.  It might have been at one time in SO's history, but not today.

Comment: @RobertHarvey is there no way to migrate to Programmers? I dont want it to be closed because I genuinely wanted to know something about it. I just need future answers too, be it from anywhere

Comment: In my opinion, the post has already been adequately answered.  You even accepted the answer.  Even if I wanted to, I'm barred from migrating a post that old.

Comment: Do a Google search for "timtowtdi".  You'll get more information than you ever wanted to know about the subject.

Comment: @RobertHarvey See do we need to close all the threads that has been answered or accepted? That's not the point here. I felt my question shouldn't have been closed (irrespective of its age, number of answers). The gist of the discussion is if it's not a real question, or if it cant be answered objectively, or if its too localized. Can you elaborate on that why the question is "It's not on-topic. " as you say?

Comment: The following things are on-topic at StackOverflow: a specific programming problem,
a software algorithm,
software tools,
practical answerable problems.

Comment: @RobertHarvey you are helping me by answering the question. You could post it as an answer in my question but for that the question shouldn't be closed. That's the point. If a question is valid, ppl will have answer to it irrespective of its age. Now its not present. I'm sad why no one is really answering to "why the question is/was not valid"

Comment: @RobertHarvey yes, and my question is not practically answerable? What about the answer that received 4 upvotes? Did not answer practically?

Comment: @nawfal - Just look at the 4 points in the very beginning of the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). You're not asking about a specific programming problem, algorithm, software tool, or a practical, answerable problem. What you're asking about is conceptual, which is off-topic. Whereas [Programmers SE's FAQ states](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq): "Programmers — Stack Exchange is a site for professional programmers who are interested in getting expert answers on conceptual questions about software development." Good luck! :)

Comment: @jmort253 hmmm, in that case I'll ask the meta community to help me migrate the question to Programmers.

Comment: @nawfal - Again, can't be done. [Questions more than 60 days old can't be migrated.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151890/disable-migration-for-questions-older-than-60-days). However, since you're really adamant about this, might I suggest that you jump into [The Whiteboard - Programmers Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/the-whiteboard) and see if you could repost your question there?

Comment: @jmort253 ok thanks. Please incorporate that too to your answer and I will accept.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I do not understand why my answer was deleted. If the question is more fit for Programmers, and since the question is too old to migrate, one option I have is to delete the question from SO and then post it in Programmers. That's what I answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This actually -- under the hood -- isn't a terrible question. But before asking for it to be reopened, I'd suggest getting rid of the part that asks for a list of examples. Those types of questions tend to lead to answers that really don't explain anything.  However, from the FAQ:

> If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here. However, if your motivation is **“I would like others to explain ______ to me”**, then you are probably OK.
>
> - emphasis is mine

Instead, I'd suggest just highlighting the fact that you want an explanation.

There's no guarantee it would be reopened, and really, like others said, you got your answer. Also, I'll add that it seems like it's not really on topic here, but had it been newer, it would be on topic on Programmers SE.

Comment: The request for limited code examples is OK... It's the subject matter that is not the best fit.

Comment: I guess I should add that it's really not on topic here, but it does seem like it might be on topic on Programmers. I'm not suggesting it be migrated though; it's too old...

Comment: Ok I'll do that. Thanks for more sensible answer