# Should the "hello world" contest be migrated to codegolf and unlocked?

Tags: discussion, migration, specific-question, locked-questions

**[This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/284797/871050)** question is known for the famous Jon-Skeet-made-a-1-byte-program-to-output-"Hello World", it's currently locked under Stack Overflow, however, this question is valid in my eyes over on Code Golf.

Shouldn't the question be migrated there and unlocked?

Comment: Besides it being an older question now, migration would instantly make it the highest voted question on Code Golf, which is usually not a desired effect of migration.

Comment: Note that you *cannot* migrate a question over 60 days old now; see [Disable migration for questions older than 60 days](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/151890) Not even moderators can migrate this question to Code Golf.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha where has Jon Skeet answered the question? I mean which of the answer is his? I don't see his name anywhere. The guy who has made 1 byte solution is somebody else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

This can lead to fun and even interesting discussions but there is no contest. And it's clearly not constructive, whatever the site, and Jon's answer only points to this fact (it is, in my opinion, a perfectly valid answer even if he could have made it 0 byte).

Answer (score 0):

Questions that are more than 60 days old cannot be migrated, not even from moderators.

Apart that, the question already has 31 answers, and the highest voted one has a score of 398. Even supposing it still possible to add a new answer that says something new, the new answer would not probably reach the first page of answers.

Probably the question could be acceptable for Code Golf, even though on Code Golf it is the code length that is checked, not the length of the binary code produced compiling the code. Questions need two requirements:

- An objective primary winning criterion, so that it is possible to indisputably decide which entry should win
- A clear specification of what constitutes a correct submission

Answers don't follow the requirements, which are:

- Be a serious contender for the winning criteria in use.
- Should be golfed, that is, compacted to the maximum degree possible:

  - This means, at a minimum, using single-character variable, function, and class names, and removing all unnecessary whitespace.
  - You are encouraged to include a non-golfed version (using real variable/function/class names, and using standard code indentation) underneath the golfed version, possibly with some comments, to help readers understand your submission.

For example, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/351152/225647), and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/285684/225647) are not really contenders, as in the first case, "Hello word" is not output from the assembly code, but from Bash; in the second case, "Hello world" is output from a interrupt handler, whose binary output is not 20 bytes long.