# Deleting questions older than 60 days

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I have known that any question older than 60 days cannot be migrated, but closed by the moderator.
Can I flag to delete a question order than 60 days ? Can the moderator delete it?

**UPDATE**
In a Stack Exchange site, I flagged an old question to delete. But the moderator misunderstood and down-voted and closed the question. I did leave a comment "TO DELETE".
Can the closed question be deleted by the moderator? 
Is there a significant way to flag to delete a question so that it might not confuse with migration or close?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151890/disable-migration-for-questions-older-than-60-days

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case of [the specific question you flagged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9920374/shared-folder-anti-copy), yes, even moderators cannot migrate something over 60 days old, but that question wouldn't have been migrated in any case. You had cross-posted this same question already on Super User, so rather than add a duplicate to the target site, it's standard procedure to close the local one as being off topic.

As for the downvote, when a question is closed as being off topic, it is automatically downvoted by the system. This isn't something we control, so the moderator involved didn't explicitly downvote your question.

You can flag any question for deletion at any time with a custom flag, but please be detailed as to why you believe it should be deleted. If there's any redeeming value at all to a question (good question, good answers, etc.), we're most likely going to let the question stay. In this case, you could have flagged that this had already been cross-posted to Super User and no longer belonged here, and we'd probably have deleted it.

I've gone ahead and removed the question for you.

Comment: Thank you, Brad. I did want to delete that question because I posted the same topic to Super User without migration. Thus, I flagged it to delete. This was because of my lack of experience using the site feature.

Comment: @Sithu - Yeah, it's usually best to include as much information as possible with a flag, because we handle hundreds of them a day and sometimes we don't see all of the context around a question when asked to act on it. Bringing it to Meta (as you did) or flagging it again with more detail is the right thing to do in this case.

Comment: To wit: "TO DELETE" is not a helpful flag note. Explaining _why_ something needs to be deleted is crucial.

Comment: @ÄlËverett, Yes, you are right. But I could not find how we should explain crucially while flagging in the FAQ. I hope this question explains well how we should flag.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, questions older than 60 days can be deleted both by moderators and 10k users. There is no age restriction for deletion.

Part of the reason why migrations are blocked after 60 days is that they can be disruptive to the receiving community - especially if it has a disproportionate amount of votes in a small community.

For deletions this is not a problem as the question simply disappears.

Answer (score 3):

It's only the migration that is not allowed, when the question is older than 60 days. Other actions, like closing, or deleting a question are still allowed, from normal users, and moderators.