# Can we PLEASE stop deleting these very useful old questions?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, flags, migration, deleted-questions

Earlier, I flagged a question for migration to [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com), here:
[Graphical Diff For Mac OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187064/graphical-diff-for-mac-os-x)

My logic was that this question had valuable answers, and was quite popular (489 upvotes, 134 stars), but was obviously off topic for SO.

Instead, Andrew Barber came in and nuked the question entirely. In my opinion, this a scenario where even a historical lock would have been better than a nuke, as this is a great aggregation of tools for SO

It is, however, possible that the flag was mis-read, so I'll post a screenshot of it below:

[image]

Please, can we have some limit to the nuking of questions that have more than say 100 upvotes? Maybe require two moderators to take action when deletin a question like this, but this type of content should NOT be deleted, even if off topic.

Comment: 228k views. I'd say that's worthy of a historical lock.

Comment: Yes, please.  This is why we have an historical lock.  Deleting good content is antithetical to this site's stated goal of "making the internet better."  And the lock prevents them from becoming "broken windows."

Comment: These old, closed, guaranteed to become out of date shopping questions? Yeah, keep *those* around.

Comment: I can see how you want that migrated since Ask Different seems to accept those types of questions. But it's older than 60 days.

Comment: @Anthony thats why I wanted it migrated to a more appropriate site. Those questions are a bit more frequent over there.

Comment: Related: [Disable migration for questions older than 60 days](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/151890)

Comment: @Richard - migrating old questions is generally frowned upon in general, fyi—even if the question isn't otherwise off topic for SO.

Comment: Yes, but this question was already a CW. No reputation losses would occur.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII, there's an appropriate site on the SE network for old, closed, out-of-date shopping questions? Has the world come to this>

Comment: @Anthony - OP asked that the question be given an historical lock, not be re-opened.  I wouldn't call that "keeping around"—except perhaps in a myopic sense.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram indeed, according to apple.SE's FAQ: `third-party hardware and software for Apple products`. This falls under that category.

Comment: @AdamRackis, historical locks might be good for content that is still useful 10 years from now. I don't think a list of software tools from 2008-2011 are quite so useful in 2023, unless we aim to be the next internet archive site.

Comment: @Anthony - I don't think lack of usefulness 10 years from now is a good reason to remove content completely.  Otherwise why don't we start nuking [this stuff](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb5)

Comment: If I thought I could get away with it...

Comment: @AdamRackis: Or [this stuff](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm not so sure this is a good question to keep around. Here's a few reasons why:

- Barely any inbound links that aren't from content farms
- Not well maintained (the answers are a mess, and no one has even tried to collect them into one answer in over 4 years)

On the other hand, it does have a lot of page views, and it maybe has useful information? Google has plenty of links for 'Mac Diff tools', so I don't think we're filling a void that isn't otherwise already filled.

I'm on the fence on this one. If we lock it, then the answers will quickly go out of date, and if we just leave it closed, someone will attempt to re-open it and we'll have to keep an eye on it (not something I'm fond of).

It had its day. I just don't think this one is in good enough shape to keep around.

**EDIT**: As another user pointed out in the comments, it looks like Ask Different already has [its own version of this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/10099/what-file-comparison-tool-can-i-use-under-os-x/).

1. Get 10K on Stack Overflow
2. Answer question on Ask Different with a list of all diff tools listed on Stack Overflow, plus all the curated answers from Ask Different.
3. PROFIT.

Comment: Why isn't migration an option here? I understand that there may be issues with migration on non-CW posts with reputation, but that shouldn't be an issue in this case, should it? And you cannot tell me that the mods absolutely don't have a way to migrate this to another SE site where it will be maintained.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII I'm telling you we do not have the ability to migrate that post even if we wanted to. To your second point, this question hasn't been well maintained in 4 years, why would that change if it were undeleted?

Comment: Because Apple.SE's focus *is* those types of questions. They encourage and nourish them.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII migration is disabled on questions that are more than 60 days old.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII The only people who could even possibly do it is the SE community team, and I'm not sure they would.

Comment: Really? Im surprised that they don't allow mods to do that. I can understand why 3k users can't, but not mods. Very odd indeed.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII you can read all about the reasoning here on the [original Meta proposal for the 60 day limit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151890/disable-migration-for-questions-older-than-60-days).

Comment: If Ask Diff nourished and wanted them it would have asked its own version in the years since it's been up instead of looking to poach old outdated material from other sites http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/10099/what-file-comparison-tool-can-i-use-under-os-x/ @ric

Comment: @random Obviously, apple.SE doesn't have the user-base of SO. However, if it had more inbound links from that question I'm confident that it would be better maintained. It's a chicken & egg scenario.

Comment: Deleting the SO version is in the best interest then so that it no longer takes any search engine hits, allowing Ask Diff to potentially take over the rankings @ric

Comment: So shopping questions **ARE** on topic *somewhere* in the SE network!!!

Comment: @Richard - random is right here, and I don't often say that.  Apple.SE has their own version of the question up and active, so this one should probably just die a quiet death.

Comment: @AdamRackis yes, they are. When you have a website dedicated to a company/os, there's only so much you can talk about hardware wise without getting into different software reccomendations.

Comment: Reopen votes expire, so I don't think there's much of a danger of it getting reopened. After all, it's been closed for over a year and hasn't been reopened yet despite its high number of views

Comment: I still don't agree with the deletion, but seeing as I have [done as you outlined](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/87188), I will accept this and move on.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII But you forgot step 3: PROFIT.  You made it CW.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker none of that was my content. It would have been 'stolen' rep.