# Request to migrate a popular deleted question

Tags: support, migration

Here's a popular graphic design related question that was closed then deleted from Stackoverflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58807/can-a-programmer-become-a-decent-graphic-designer

Archived version:

http://web.archive.org/web/20100813080556/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58807/can-a-programmer-become-a-decent-graphic-designer

It's clearly offtopic for stackoverflow, but the top answer is very good quality and **on topic for the graphic design stack exchange** site (http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com).

That was a very useful question to link to for newbies struggling to grasp the basics, and there are a lot of links to that question that have now gone dead. It'd be great if it could be migrated to the design site.

---

(there are also a lot of poor quality answers, but the GD.SE mods can probably clean those up)

Comment: If you want that content reposted, create a suitable question on that site and transfer the content over. The answer's owner is still active on Stack Overflow, you could probably ping them to see if they want to repost the answer themselves.

Comment: @Mat Thanks, is there a way to ping them other than leaving a comment on an unrelated question?

Comment: No, unless they left contact info in their profile, or are active in chat and you can find them there. (Or you get an SO mod involved.)

Comment: @user568458 if that's unsuccessful, you could consider making the answer a community wiki. Or just go ahead and reap the rep, since you deserve some credit for taking the question where it belongs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A similar question to that one came up, so I pinged the guy who answered it suggesting he repost his old answer to the new question.

He's done so and now that content is back live in the right place with the right person getting credit for it:

[Coming from a programming background, where should I start to learn web design?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/18630/coming-from-a-programming-background-where-should-i-start-to-learn-web-design?noredirect=1#comment25363_18630)

Answer (score 4):

Old questions, those [older than 60 days (2 months)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151890/disable-migration-for-questions-older-than-60-days), cannot be migrated.

Feel free to repost the question on the target site, *provided it is on topic* for the target site. Check the [target site FAQ](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/faq#questions) to be sure.

The original question and aswers were posted under the CC-wiki license, so with a simple attribution statement you are free to re-use them on another Stack Exchange site.

Comment: It's actually 60 days.

Comment: @Mysticial: I knew there was a 6 in there somewhere..