# Is it ever acceptable to cross-post questions that are too old to migrate?

Tags: discussion, migration

I'm facing a difficult dilemma here: several months ago, I asked [a question on Stack Overflow that should have been posted on Superuser instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13890214/is-it-possible-to-synchronize-userscripts-between-google-chrome-installations), and the question is now too old to migrate. In this case, would it be acceptable to post a duplicate of the question on Superuser.com, since there's apparently no other way to migrate it now?

I'm concerned that the question would be downvoted for lack of research effort if I posted it on Superuser, since it already has an answer on Stack Overflow. On the other hand, if I didn't migrate the question, then it would eventually be deleted, and then I wouldn't be able to migrate it to the correct site. I would post a duplicate of the question on Superuser and then delete the original Stack Overflow question (if that were possible), but there's no way to delete the question now, since it already has an answer.

Comment: You can delete the question since the answer is your own. First, unaccepted it, then delete it and then delete the question.

Comment: yey, on superuser already

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As a general rule, a question closed as off-topic on one site is fair game to re-ask on a different site where it *is* on-topic.

When folks talk negatively about cross-posting, they're nearly always referring to posting the exact same question on multiple sites simultaneously - this is rude, and shows a lack of willingness to understand the scopes of any of the sites involved. When a question has been rejected by one site (and particularly after *months* have passed), I don't see the problem.

In this specific case, I went ahead and migrated the question just to save you the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a grey area.

- If you want to post the exact **same** question on another site, then you should *either* delete the original question, or close it (if it qualifies for closure).
- If you **tailor/change** the question to suit the second site's community and scope, then you *could* cross-post with the normal riders (in scope, and follows community standards). However, this is not encouraged *unless*, the first post of the question did not get you a helpful response within a reasonable time frame.

Comment: What is the downvote for? Even Shog's answer says pretty much the same thing.

Answer (score -2):

Flag for migration by moderator.  "Too old to migrate" only pertains to migration via closing, to us plebeian users.

Comment: Applies to everyone, including moderators. There is a work-around though, for cases that do require it. [I mentioned this when the restriction was put in](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151890/disable-migration-for-questions-older-than-60-days#comment436190_151899), and can still count the number of times it's come up on the fingers of one hand.