# Closing votes as off-topic: two options for SuperUser?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, migration, off-topic

Whenever I vote to close a question as "Off topic" because they should be in SuperUser, I find it complicated to know which one of the two options I should select:

This:

> Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic
>   for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily
>   for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.

Or this?

> This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network
>   --> and select SuperUser

I guess many people are also confused, because the voters normally vote on the same option as the first one voting did.

So, what's the standard way to do it? Isn't a bit tricky to have two status for the same "closing reason"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network --> and select SuperUser

The above is a vote for migration to Super User.  By selecting it you're saying that you think the question should be migrated *as is*.  If that's the case, or if you can edit the question into shape, go ahead and vote for migration.

I usually use the other option,

> Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.

when I'm reasonably certain that a question has already been asked and answered on Super User, or when I think the question isn't of sufficient quality to migrate, but want to encourage the OP to search on SU for an answer.

Comment: Mmmm interesting! And what if I do not have certainty about a question being asked or not in [su]? Meaning, what's the best default option to vote? And if we choose the 2nd, won't it lead to cross-duplicated questions?

Comment: @fedorqui You can search on SU if you're not sure. If a question gets closed without being answered, it will probably be deleted eventually, so cross-site duplicates won't be much of a problem.  If a duplicate question on SO does get good answers, we need to consider migrating it so the new answers can be merged on SU.

Answer (score 2):

If you know that it belongs  to Superuser, select "This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network" and select "SuperUser". This way is for the migration to SuperUser.

This option is only avaiable to new questions (<s>AFAIK age <1 week</s> [age < 60 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151890/disable-migration-for-questions-older-than-60-days/)), after that you can only select the other option.

Comment: [60 days is the migration time limit.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151890/disable-migration-for-questions-older-than-60-days/)