# No favourite stars showing in the Questions tab in Meta

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, bookmarks

I just noticed that the number of users who favorited a question is not showing in the Questions tab of the user's profile. This is happening here in the Meta site, but not in Stackoverflow for example.

See for example [the questions tab in my profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/209901/fedorqui?tab=questions&sort=votes):

> [image: question list on Meta Stack Exchange profile]

If I go the the question itself: [Closing votes as off-topic: two options for SuperUser?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198429/closing-votes-as-off-topic-two-options-for-superuser), then we see the number of users who favorited the question:

> [image: individual question showing "favorite" count]

However, [in Stack Overflow for example it does show](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1983854/fedorqui?tab=questions):

[image: Stack Overflow question list]

Comment: Probably related to the new profile page that is being tested on MSE.  I wonder if the missing favorite indicators is intentional (making this a feature request) or an accidental omission (making this a bug)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This *is* related to the new profile page, in that we were testing a few different layouts for the activity pages.

It is however, a left-over from a layout we didn't go with (and which meant we didn't have enough space to also have the favorite stars). Of course, this isn't currently the case.

I removed the code that left the stars out - with you in the next build.

Comment: Thanks! I see the stars are back in the Questions tab, you were fast :)