# Move question on converting a shapefile from SO to GIS.stackexchange

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, migration

This question

[Convert a shapefile (.shp) to xml/json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223979/convert-a-shapefile-shp-to-xml-json)

seems a perfectly appropriate question for GIS.stackexchange.  It is even referenced in some of the answers on that site.  Seems unnecessary to be on SO and closed and not on GIS and open.

Comment: If a question belongs on the site it was asked on, we don't migrate it, even if it conceptually belongs "more" elsewhere.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it *could* be. [As I said before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151890/disable-migration-for-questions-older-than-60-days#comment436190_151899),

> if you come across a good, answered question that has been closed (correctly) as off-topic but would be a good fit somewhere else, post about it on Meta. We'll take care of them.

In this case though, I don't think that question was correctly closed. Unless there's a non-programming reason to convert a file to JSON that I'm not aware of. So for now, I've just re-opened it.

If it gets closed again, ping me here & I'll migrate it.

Comment: How is that not a tool recommendation question?

Comment: It states a problem to be solved, @Wooble.

Comment: Are people posting questions asking for a library/tool recommendation that don't want to use the tool or library that's recommended to solve some problem? Why have that close reason at all?

Comment: @Wooble: have you followed the link in that close reason? The problem is that, yes, folks *do* ask these questions without a clearly-defined problem - or at least, without stating it anywhere. The end result is half-assed, spammy lists of recommendations that may or may not solve *anyone's* problem. If you can actually define a real problem you're trying to solve, and there happens to be a tool available to solve that specific problem... Great!