# Why was my question put on hold for the "recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic" reason?

Tags: support

This is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20111951/looking-for-a-way-to-display-us-map-with-colored-zones-polygons-and-markers-on-a) I posted. I am asking for a very specific library. I posted specific requirements. I don't understand the concern that this question is going to solicit opinionated answers. I didn't ask a "What's your favorite...?". I am expecting some good targeted answers and I will choose the library that best fits the requirements.

I don't see an opportunity for soliciting spam either. There's only one answer so far.

If there's a better way to ask this question and there's an issue with my wording, please make some suggestions. I will edit my question.

**UPDATE:**
If people are just going to telling me because it's in the FAQ, I already know this fact. The reason already has a link! Unless you know a way to make my question better, your answer won't help much.

Answer (score 15):

> I was wondering if there are similar libraries which meet ALL the requirements.

Um. That's asking for a library, right?

Which is not a good question for Stack Overflow, hence closed, as the close reason states:

> "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

You have not asked for specific coding help, but for help to find a library.

Comment: Yes it's a library and I know it's a library and I know it's in the FAQ. I am questioning the reason why these questions are not allowed. Being able to choose a library should be considered a kind of coding help.  That's what you do sometimes when you start a development project. Choosing the right tool.

Comment: @Abdu - And in 2 years, would the top library still be the correct answer? You end up getting a bunch of answers, most of (all of?) which don't go into depth and which get voted by **popularity**. We tried such questions and they simply don't work well, so are now not allowed.

Comment: -1, Shog9 just told me these questions are good. ( http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208397/move-question-on-converting-a-shapefile-from-so-to-gis-stackexchange/208399#comment665013_208399 )

Comment: @Wooble _...and you believed him?_ ;P On a more serious note: That's not what Shog9 says in that comment. Don't ask for a library/tool/whatever. Instead, describe the problem you are trying to solve. If there's a library/tool/whatever that solves the problem, great, it will appear in an answer soon enough.

Comment: I don't see a qualitative difference between the OP's question and the one mentioned in that post. This may be a sign it's time for me to stop closing questions if I can't understand the policies.

Comment: @Wooble See [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139399/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) (also by Shog, and not coincidentally linked in the close reason itself) that described how to take a library question question and turn it into an appropriate question.  The OP kinda did half of it, but didn't really finish the process.  Namely, at the end of the day the question shouldn't be asking, "what library can I use to do X?", it should be asking, "how can I do  X?"

Answer (score 8):

Let's assume I was you and I was interested in getting library suggestions my question would go like this (I'm not familiar with any of the topics mentioned so my question is a free-hand drawn circle in words).
*Here we go...*

> I drew the polygons for the states of the US using Inkscape and
>   displayed the svg map using mapSVG library because I think the flexibility I'm looking for is only possible in SVG, like so:
>
> ```
>    var states = [ { lbl: 'MA', poly: [ {1,1}, {3,4}  ] }, ...];
>
>    function Draw() {
>        var svg= new Map();
>        for(var i=0;states.length; i++)
>        {
>            svg.DrawPoly(states[i].poly);
>        }
>    }
> ```
>
> I draw the markers with the `DrawSprite` function but it looks like
>   their coordinate system is off.
>
> Does anybody know which transformation is needed and how that needs to be
>   applied? Can I use such a transform for Panning and Zooming as well?

As you can see I show effort, with something I already know. I state what I want to achieve and what doesn't work yet/is hard to accomplish. In the lead-in I explain why I think I have to use this SVG library.

I envision this question will get answers that will solve the issues in the current problemspace, or provide alternatives for the same functionality with other libraries.

Comment: This is a good answer. See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139399/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question/139404#139404 - if there's a specific problem to be solved, focus on that; don't jump ahead to what you *think* the answer will be.

Answer (score 5):

The close reason reads:

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Even if the question does not necessarily attract opinionated answers, it's still off topic, because that is how we defined the site scope. However, the latter part still applies. This solicits opinion ("I think this library is the best") and spam ("I worked on this project, click my link.").

But really, when it comes down to it, the question is off topic. That is how the site scope is defined. My suggestion is to ask specific questions about the implementation of a library, as opposed to asking for a specific library. Unfortunately, this question may not be salvageable.

Comment: Wow, I was _super_ ninja'd on this answer.

Comment: Hmmm.. I have never seen that sort of spam you mentioned and I read tens of hundreds of questions on SO.

Comment: @Abdu Well, I see it pretty much every single day, or at least most days.  Perhaps you're just not noticing it.

Comment: @Abdu: We've gotten very good at deleting the spam and closing these kinds of questions.  That's why you don't see it.

Answer (score 4):

See [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139399/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and [this blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/).

You're still asking for a recommendation. You've given criteria, but it still is a recommendation question.

There is something to be said for allowing recommendation questions with very specific criteria, but usually those are two narrow to get an answer, or not narrow enough to avoid becoming a list-thread.

You may have more luck asking about it in the relevant [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/) room