# How long after being asked can a question be migrated to another site?

Tags: discussion, migration, moderator-abilities

I recently flagged a closed question for moderator attention because it was off-topic and would have been better suited to another SE site. However, my flag was declined, and I was told "it's too old to migrate". So how long is a question eligible for migration? I can't seem to find the rule for this. I would like to know so I don't waste moderators' time in the future by filing impossible requests.

Note that the fact that the question was already closed is important here. Normally, if a question is off-topic, I would choose an "off-topic" flagging option. If the question can still be migrated, there is an option called "This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network" under "Flagging > Closing > Off-Topic". If the question is too old to be migrated, this option doesn't appear. However, if the question is already closed, the entire "Off-topic" flagging menu is unavailable because it's part of the "Closing" flag menu.

Comment: From the linked faq: "Only questions which are younger than 60 days can be migrated to other sites. This rule applies even to moderators on the site."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Questions can be migrated up to 60 days after being asked.

See [Disable migration for questions older than 60 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151890/disable-migration-for-questions-older-than-60-days)

Comment: I'd really love a "Questions older than 60 days cannot be migrated" radio button in the decline dialog. If you know anybody who can swing that...

Comment: Heh. Mentioned to the relevant swingers.