# Migration of existing questions and answers to a new more focused Stack Exchange site

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, migration

When a new Stack Exchange site is created, there are existing questions and answers that were reasonably placed at the time, given that the new site was not available then. With the creation of a more focused site, are those existing questions and answers intended to be migrated to the new site? Where is this documented? Is it the choice of the existing site or the new site as to whether the question are to be moved?

Answer (score 6):

The first rule of migration is that if a question is on-topic where it is, [we don't migrate it away](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/).  The question was asked and answered in its original community and that community shouldn't be deprived of that content.  You can, of course, ask *new* related or follow-on questions on the new site.

Older questions (> 60 days) also can't be migrated without special intervention, which is usually only applied when a site is shutting down.

Answer (score 1):

New sites that overlap existing sites such as they would [cannibalise users](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/an-area-51-apology-and-clarification/) from existing sites are not encouraged.

Questions over [60 days old can't be migrated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151890/disable-migration-for-questions-older-than-60-days) this is likely to cover most questions asked that might be migrated from a site like Stack Overflow.

Other questions might be migrated manually by moderators as a result of users flagging them, but there won't be any mass migration.