# What to do with an old question that may receive better answers on a different SE?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

(Note: I have a specific question in mind but I'm asking this one in the general case as it may apply to others. I've added an explanation for the specific case at the end.)

It can happen that a question is on-topic on more than one Stack Exchange website. Unless I'm mistaken, asking it on either of them is acceptable.

If it is posted on one of the websites but has not received an answer that solves the problem in a timely fashion, and there is reason to think that it can receive better answers on the other website, should it be re-asked on that one?

Migration may not be an option due to the question being [too old](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151890/disable-migration-for-questions-older-than-60-days).

The question that prompted this one is [New 3DS microSD Management - connecting from Linux](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/207147/new-3ds-microsd-management-connecting-from-linux). I believe it is equally on-topic in Arqade and Superuser, but that the people most qualified to answer it may be on Superuser, as it is essentially about SMB/samba.

Comment: tl;dr: go ahead and re-ask it.