# Moving a two-month old post across sites denied

Tags: discussion, questions, duplicate-questions, migration, site-crossover

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63178743/11143763) two month back. It got answer which does not quite  work for me. A while after I came back to the problem at hand and decided to flag my post to have it moved to [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com) or [CS.SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com). Yet, I have been denied that due to question being asked more than 60 days ago:
[image]

What shall I do to ask this question again and avoid duplicates across the sites? Would closing work, or is there something else that should be done?

Besides, why do we want to deny old posts being moved in the first place?

Comment: Well the canned message is not true. As 60 days haven't passed between juli 30th and september 17th.

Comment: @Luuklag true, thank you. Is it possible to reflag then?

Comment: While another moderator could act differently, I don't think they are very likely to consider, as the question is closing in to those 60 days. Better then to just delete it and post it on a different site.

Comment: @Luuklag the question got answer. Deleting it would be unfair to the answerer, even though I do not reckon it to be quite right. Would closing work?

Comment: The original feature request for this age limit, [Disable migration for questions older than 60 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151890/disable-migration-for-questions-older-than-60-days), contains a full explanation about why it's a bad idea to migrate older questions that have been answered, which I feel addresses this question well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If a question is not off-topic I see no reason to migrate it.

Also it is unclear what you want to happen. A mod is not going to judge if your question is a better fit for Computer Science or Math. You have to convince them with proper guidance and a single task. Mods do not think for you. They click buttons on our behalf. Unclear flags should be declined. The flag outcome is correct, Martijn picked/typed the wrong reason.

It is your responsibility to select the correct site. I see nothing in the question that would make me think Math.se is a good migration target. But I'm not a regular there so I don't know exactly what goes and don't goes on those sites.

If you upvoted the current answer, you could try to undo your vote (might need an edit to unlock votes, uugghhh) and then delete the question yourself. You can then re-post on a  better fitting SE site.

Alternatively try to rephrase your question a bit so it could go as a new question on a site you prefer. Because in general cross-posting is frowned upon. You can prevent the frowning by following the advice given by [Mast](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/354404/moving-a-two-month-old-post-across-sites-denied/354411?noredirect=1#comment1184357_354411):

> Don't forget to add a link to your original question so people can see the original answer and don't have to rehash the same story. Also indicate in the new question what you're looking for that differs from what you already got.

The reasoning for not moving a question after 60 days is found in [Disable migration for questions older than 60 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151890/disable-migration-for-questions-older-than-60-days) and I quote the infamous Shog9 here:

> Migration works best as a way to salvage good but off-topic questions and give them new life on a site where they can thrive. But shuffling old, answered, on-topic questions around for the hell of it is a waste of everyone's time.

Comment: I think significantly rephrasing (tailor it to the target site) and reposting is indeed the way to go. Don't forget to add a link to your original question so people can see the original answer and don't have to rehash the same story. Also indicate in the new question what you're looking for that differs from what you already got.

Comment: It’s not a canned comment, by the way. I just misread the date, June vs July. Otherwise I’d have written a rejection along the reasoning given here.